# PHP redirect: Chrome closes window

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, google-chrome, redirect

I need to do some redirects after processing in PHP. This processing is done in a new window after a link is clicked. However, in Chrome, whenever I try to click the link, it closes right away, somehow sensing and blocking the redirect right away. It works if the link is not opened with `target="_blank"`.

Sites like Pricerunner handle the redirect flawlessly: http://www.pricerunner.co.uk/pli/2-3155408/TVs/Samsung-UE40KU6000-Compare-Prices.

How do I make my site work like Pricerunner? Should I skip `target="_blank"` and do some JavaScript handling instead?

Comment: Can you write down some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

try to create a redirecting page with following two lines of code:

```
header("your/site/page.php");
exit();
```

it will send a response header with a redirect to the browser. And `exit()` will stop all the execution after this point. So the further loading will cancel here and the new page will "load".